# Lower bounds on alternative models of multiparty communication complexity

Tags: lower-bounds, communication-complexity

I'm a newcomer to communication complexity, and so far I've read the chapter in Arora-Barak and some papers giving lower bounds in various applications.

A priori the definition of multiparty communication complexity is strange. Forgetting the fruitful applications of the "number on the forehead" model, I would imagine people first thought to have each player see only their *own* input and not *all but their own* inputs. The computation of the protocol would happen in parallel, and communication could be player-to-player or broadcast.

I have reason to believe that lower bounds in such a model will aid me in proving lower bounds in a problem I'm currently looking at. Does this model have a name? What is known about it?

Comment: It's known as "number in hand".

Comment: And that was enough to lead me to the SODA '12 Phillips-Verbin-Zhang paper which has a lower bound on graph connectivity for this model. Very much in the realm of what I was looking for. Put an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Rather, you should answer your own question with a summary of the result you mention, and accept it (you will be able to, eventually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "number in hand" model is the one I was thinking of, and there is quite a bit of literature about it. In particular I found this paper of Jeff Phillips, Elad Verbin, and Qin Zhang from SODA 2012 [1]. In particular they prove lower bounds on the problem I was interested in using, the undirected graph connectivity problem, of $\Omega(nk / \log^2(k))$. Here $k$ is the number of edges provided to each player and $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph.

[1] http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2559

Comment: Conference version: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2095158 and note that for $k=2$ an $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound is known for undirected connectivity.  Also, in the paper $k$ is the number of parties, who partition the edges of the graph between themselves, not the number of edges provided to each party.